# How to get time stamp messages with sender time

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am developing a chat application. In that if i am online, sending and receiving messages with current date and time is fine. But if i am offline again coming to online after 2 hours, i am receiving messages with current time itself, but i want to receive the message time with sender time. help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

send part

```
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
                data = new Msg();
                data.setMessage(text);
                data.setSenderName(userFrom);
                String date = DateAndTime.getCurrentDate();
                data.setDate(date);
                String time = DateAndTime.getCurrentTime();
                data.setTime(time);
                data.setSender(true);
                MessageListAdapter.messagesItems.add(data);
                notifyMyAdapter();
            }
```

receive part

```
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                String from = to + "@localhost/Smack";
                if (from.equalsIgnoreCase(message.getFrom())) {
                    if (message.getBody() != null) {
                        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                        Msg data = new Msg();
                        String subject = message.getSubject();
                        if (subject == null) {
                            String text = message.getBody();
                            data.setMessage(text);
                            data.setSenderName(NAME);
                            String date = DateAndTime.getCurrentDate();
                            data.setDate(date);
                            String time = DateAndTime.getCurrentTime();
                            data.setTime(time);
                            data.setSender(false);
                            MessageListAdapter.messagesItems.add(data);

                            // Add the incoming message to the list view
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    notifyMyAdapter();
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have to do is while publishing the message  `data.setCreatedAtTime(System.currentTimeMillis();`
the good thing about `System.currentTimeMillis();` is  that it is in epoch and millisecondsformat and would remain constant over all timeZones.
now on the reciever side you can convert the milliseconds into which ever format you desire